# where in Magento is the function that "Update Shopping Cart" button uses

Tags: php, magento

i thought it was the `updatePostAction()` in app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php but i put in a `Mage::log` call but the log file it was supposed to create never appeared (**logging is on cause i've created a bunch of new logging files**)

i did a text search in all of magento looking for other declarations of `updatePostAction()` just incase if a local/community module was overriding the one in app/code/core but it only found the 1 instance of it so obviously i don't have the right function

i'm trying to add some new functionality to the button (and to the cart) but i need to see the code for it first to see what needs to be add/changed for i get to work

EDIT 1: i know the function i'm looking for edits the sales_flat_quote tables when you chnage the quantity of an item in the cart, how it does i don't know (why i need to see the code before i add my functionality)

Comment: That's where it POSTs. Throw a die statement in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using some j2tajaxcheckout module or some other AJAX cart-related module?
I ran into the same issue as you yesterday and found out that the javascript of the module changed the URL of the update button on the cart overview.

Comment: i'm using the Idev OneStepCheckout and it has an AjaxControler.php file and the only thing it has to the cart is a sidebar.php file which gets the checkout url. i only looked in app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php cause there is no app\code\core\Mage\Cart folder

Comment: took me forever to look though the code but i found out that yeh that was javascript was changing the url, after that i was able to find the right function and the Mage::log worked

Answer (score 0):

You do have to enable the log settings from the Admin interface. The settings for this can be seen from the `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings` Enabled to `Yes`.

Comment: logging is enabled, as i've said i've created a bunch of new logging files for different areas like promotions and the such